# Ubuntu minimal cd installs GRUB to USB drive

Tags: grub2, ubuntu-minimal

The installation goes fine, but when it comes to the GRUB installation, the installer tries to put it on the USB drive. For some reason, the usb drive is detected as /dev/sda and the HDD is at /dev/sdb.

I tried answering "no" to the "Install GRUB boot loader to the master boot record". It allows me to enter where GRUB should be installed, HOWEVER, when I start typing, what appears is garbage and not letters - some distorted symbols and that's all.

What should I do?

Edit:
Found a solution here: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/176050/ubuntu-server-installed-from-usb-putsgrub-on-theusb-drive-instead-of-the-hard)

However, I'm not sure whether this is the right way to do it. Is it okay to install it like this?

Comment: Yeah, it should work. I recommend mounting the partition of Ubuntu system. Then run: `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/<ubuntu-part>/ /dev/sdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to remove the USB in your link works. You are allowed to remove the USB because all the data required is already loaded (To ram/cpu cache). If you happen to miss the removing part after the clock selection, just select the go back option. This will take you to the main menu and you can remove your USB at this point. Then select "Detect Disks" when it will no longer find the USB. Proceed normally.

TL:DR It's okay to do the remove your USB solution.